# On LiveCD before install WiFi works perfect, but after install working drivers disappeared

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, broadcom

I have used ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

WiFi works as it should on LiveCD.

I opened additional drivers selected Broadcom driver and applied changes.

Then chose WiFi network, entered password and everything works great.

[image]

But when I rebooted after installation WiFi does not work

[image]

[image]

hmm, driver is not active then activating and applying changes as I did before install but:

[image]

What? It was work before I rebooted after install

How to install working driver from LiveCD?

There is no internet now. LiveCD is only one source?

Comment: I scrolled down to related topics and seen this. I think it describes your situation. [Broadcom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337689/how-do-i-get-proprietary-broadcom-drivers-to-work-after-installation?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get proprietary Broadcom drivers to work after installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337689/how-do-i-get-proprietary-broadcom-drivers-to-work-after-installation)

Comment: After installing the driver in Live, then during the install be sure to check> install third party drivers and software

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, i did it ofcourse ...

Answer (score -1):

I have read a lot of solutions and all of them recommends to install something without working WiFi adapter, without internet.

But I found a solution that is suitable for me:

To use cellular internet via usb cable. Both iOS and Android gave me network to download driver.

Comment: This is one solution given in one of the answers to the above linked duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, cellular way is worked, but it is not a solution. As I said in the boom of my question I want to run wifi adapter after installation is complete. 1) how to install proprietary driver from LiveCD or 2) how to install any open source driver from usb with all required dependencies after installation without internet